# No puedo hacer ping desde un server dedicado OVH a un dominio alojado en una instancia AWS EC2

Tags: servidor, ec2

Estoy tratando de comunicarme desde Curl desde un server dedicado en OVH a un servicio alojado en Ec2 de Amazon, pero me responde host unknow

He intentado hacer ping al dominio y me funciona desde todos sitios excepto desde el servidor dedicado.

¿Alguna sugerencia de porque puede pasar esto?

Comment: Quizás estas tratando de hacer ping desde una maquina en internet hacia una que esta en local, o bien las configuraciones de tu servidor OVH no están correctamente configuradas para comunicarse con el.

Comment: Es claramente la 2º opción pero no se que me falta en la configuracion

Answer (score 0):

Era una tonteria, me faltaba crear dicho registro en el servidor desde el que hago ping